# Tikz Braces On Top of Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting, brackets, braces

I am trying to produce the following result:

[image: d]

I've never placed tikz objects on images. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify: are you just trying to add the labelled braces to an existing image, or do you want to create that whole picture from scratch?

Comment: You can put an `\includegraphics` in a `\node`, and then draw the braces relative to the nodes.